# Detailed information about data usage in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10

I'm looking for a way to get detailed data usage  in Windows 10, something that would show the usage hour by hour (or even minute by minute) for each application.

I know about the two methods described [here](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/monitor-your-data-usage-in-windows-10/) but the first one only shows global data usage over 30 days (I need more details), and the second only shows data for built-in Windows app, and not for regular desktop apps.

Any suggestions?